# How to adjust UI.Text alpha to light up in a wave pattern?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Updated code:

```
bool countUp;
int num = 0;
string hex1, hex2, hex3;
UnityEngine.UI.Text txt;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    txt = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    // Control structure to oscillate between 0 and 255 repeatedly
    if (num >= 255)
        countUp = false;
    else if (num <= 0)
        countUp = true;

    if (countUp)
        num += 1;
    else
        num -= 1;

    // Update Hex values
    hex1 = (num/3).ToString("X");
    hex2 = (num/2).ToString("X");
    hex3 = (num/1).ToString("X");

    txt.text = "   <color=#ffffff" + hex1 + ">.</color> " +
        "<color=#ffffff" + hex2 + ">.</color> " +
        "<color=#ffffff" + hex3 + ">.</color>";
}
```

Updated visual:
[image: updated gif]

The goal is to have a behavior akin to a wave pattern in which a 'light' travels linearly and illuminates each character as it passes by. Right now each character is not behaving in the desired fashion.

I updated the code in the hopes of incrementing at different speeds to illuminate the first character faster then the second, and the second faster then the third and the same in de-illuminating.

Certain there is a more efficient way to go about this. Tried a few different tactics but it seemed the way with the greatest clarity was if/elses that determine if a number needs to be counted up to 255 or counted down to 0 and then processing the according increments/decrements.

**update1 ends here**

Acquiring color from a UI.Texts material allows one to manipulate the alpha values as shown below. As the code is now it moves the alpha up and down to create an oscillating illumination effect. When applied to the entirety of the text as a whole, the effect is less inspiring. The desired behavior is to show the light moving in a wave like pattern across the text, again shown below. Though the sample of the desired behavior is moving in a circular fashion, it serves the purpose of visualizing the result I am after.

On first thought, I believe this can be implemented with multiple text components nested onto children and then using alternating timers to create the desired behavior. However I don't believe this is the optimal way to go about this.

Is it? Is their a more efficient way to do this? I imagined doing something like GetComponent().text.Length and using a for loop to change the alpha of each character but, I never got that far.

Current code:

```
Color color;
bool bl;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    color = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().material.color;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (color.a < 0)
    {
        bl = true;
    }

    if (color.a > 1)
    {
        bl = false;
    }

    if (bl == false)
    {
        color.a -= 0.005f;
    }

    if (bl == true)
    {
        color.a += 0.005f;
    }

    GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().material.SetColor("_Color", color);
}
```

Code-in-action:
[image: Oscillating alpha values img]

Desired behavior (light moving in a wave pattern, albeit this is circular not linear):
[image: Light moving in a wave pattern]

Comment: I guarantee you that's a keyframed animation. So you can do the same, or you can do it like you suggested, its only 3 characters so its easy.

Comment: @Lestat Is that more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to go about this but I think the most straight-forward way would be to take advantage of unity's [Rich Text Features](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StyledText.html).  As documented in that link, there are options for adjusting color on a per-character basis within a single `Text` component.

Every frame, you'd rebuild the string in your `Text` component to look something like this:

```
"<color=#ffffff00>A</color><color=#ffffff7f>B</color><color=#ffffffff>C</color>"
// A is invisible, B is 50% opacity, and C is opaque White
```

To make this easily extensible, consider defining a function that accepts a character and a color and returns the markup for it:

```
public string BuildColoredString(string s, Color c) {
    string hex = c.r.ToString("X2") +
        c.g.ToString("X2") +
        c.b.ToString("X2") +
        c.a.ToString("X2");
    return string.Format("<color={0}>{1}</color>", hex, c);
}
```

Keep in mind there's a lot of potential for the optimization of this solution including the usage of `StringBuilder`. If you don't like this solution, your other options include writing a custom shader (the most difficult option if you want a glyph to have a consistent alpha within itself), your proposed method of having separate text components, or manually keyframing an animation with sprites. I like this particular solution because of its simplicity, extensibility, and consistency with Unity's built-in functionality.

---

Update:

A straight-forward mathematical solution to the alpha calculations could involve mapping a group of percentages to one full sin wave:

```
|_|___|___|___|__________________|
0%  A   B   C                   100%
     ----->
|_________|___|___|___|__________|
0%          A   B   C           100%
```

When they pass the end, they wrap around and the spacing between them can be variable to adjust the "width" of the light.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]
public class TextWave : MonoBehaviour {

    [Range(0f, 1.0f)]
    [SerializeField]
    float cyclesPerSecond = 1.0f;

    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    [SerializeField]
    float spacingFactor = 0.5f;

    int charCount;
    float[] percents;
    Text textComponent;

    Color baseColor;
    string baseString;

    void Awake() {
        textComponent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
        baseString = textComponent.text;
        baseColor = textComponent.color;
        charCount = baseString.Length;
        percents = new float[charCount];

        // Space the percentages
        for (int i = 0; i < charCount; ++i) {
            percents[i] = (spacingFactor / charCount) * i;
        }

        StartCoroutine(Step());
    }

    IEnumerator Step() {
        while(true) {
            StepPercents(cyclesPerSecond * Time.deltaTime);
            textComponent.text = BuildColoredString();
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void StepPercents(float step) {
        for (int i = 0; i < charCount; ++i) {
            percents[i] -= step;
            if (percents[i] <= 0.0f) {
                percents[i] += (int)percents[i] + 1.0f;
            }
        }
    }

    string BuildColoredString() {
        string result = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < charCount; ++i) {
            Color color = GetColorFromPercent(percents[i]);
            result += FormatCharWithColor(baseString[i], color);
        }
        return result;
    }

    // Mathf.Sin(float) will return a smooth
    // curve of values between [-1, 1) resembling a `~`
    // and one wave is in the range of arguments [0f, 2π)
    Color GetColorFromPercent(float percent) {
        // Multiply by 0.5f then add 0.5 to translate graph range to [0, 1)
        var alpha = 0.5f + 0.5f * Mathf.Sin(percent * Mathf.PI * 2);
        return new Color(baseColor.r, baseColor.g, baseColor.b, alpha);
    }

    string FormatCharWithColor(char c, Color color) {
        string hex =
            ((int)(color.r * 256)).ToString("X2") +
            ((int)(color.g * 256)).ToString("X2") +
            ((int)(color.b * 256)).ToString("X2") +
            ((int)(color.a * 256)).ToString("X2");
        return string.Format("<color=#{0}>{1}</color>", hex, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the color tag to manipulate the alpha values was another idea I had though I didn't get past using words to your using of hex values instead. I can appreciate the method example but it isn't exactly clear. You specify reading in a character and color value before diving into the code but your code doesn't appear to utilize the 'character' (string s) value. Likewise I realize this is an example but it doesn't appear to be manipulating the alpha to continually oscillate between invisible and opaque

Comment: I am very grateful for the answer but I don't see how the function is actually working to accomplish the desired behavior. The example with the color tagged for each character does give me the idea to do something like oscillating a hex value between 0-255 (00 to FF) and assign this to each characters alpha pair. **EDIT:** Unsure of how StringBuilder provides optimization if I am presumably overwriting/re-writing the string each Update ?

Comment: @jtth You'd have a loop updating your alpha values, feed the characters and values through the function, and then update your `Text` component to have all those strings put together.  `StringBuilder` helps with string concatenation as it is far more efficient that doing a `string` + `string`.

Comment: @jtth Another option would be build the entire string once and then just simply update only the characters that represent the alpha values each frame, accessing them via `[]`.  This would be more efficient but might not be as re-usable.

Comment: Currently using Update as a form of loop to repeatedly update my alpha values. Ranging from 0-255 (increments up and back down). Not quite sure how to get the desired effect. Dividing the number to create different 'illumination' speeds results in a behavior close to the goal but it means some of the values don't reach full illumination. As well there is a point in which the alpha is brought from near absolute transparency to completely opaque. Not sure how this is happening either as the code literally increments/decrements in 1's. Perhaps value is breaching the max and overflowing...

Comment: @jtth You could just use [`Mathf.Sin()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Sin.html) and throw in evenly-spaced offsets for each character.

Comment: @jtth I edited my answer with a fully-functional example using percentages and a sin was to achieve the effect.

Comment: Your solution may work, it is better to do this kind of stuff with coroutine.  +1.

Comment: @Programmer I agree; adjusted.

Comment: Wow! Very elegant solution Foggzie. Minor points of detail: -multiplication in FormatCharWithColor() needs to be 255, -StartCoroutine(Step()) call is processed only once when in Awake() - if the coroutine call is placed in Update() the code functions, -adjusting spacingFactor before playing the scene or during runtime doesn't appear to perform any alterations (I see it is used in spacing the percentages).

Comment: @jtth Oh, good catch on the coroutine; I forgot to put that in a loop after changing it from `void Update()`. Another good catch on the 256 vs 255.  As for the spacing factor, that'll adjust the "width" of the light. If you make 0, all chars in the string fade in and out together; with higher values, character alphas are further apart from one another.